# Visual Studio 2013 Website Project - Change Configuration in Configuration Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configurationmanager

I have Website Project in Visual Studio 2013. I have two Publishing Profiles, one for staging and the other for production. In Configuration Manager, I can create new Active Solution Configurations but cannot add new Configurations to my drop-down, Debug is the only option.

So now when I attempt to Publish using my production profile, the web.config is getting transformed by both the Web.Debug.Config and my web.Production.Config.

How do I add new Configurations to the dropdown?

[image]

Comment: Are you doing any significant transforms in `Web.Debug.Config`?

Comment: I wouldn't say significant but they are vital. The primary changes being url rewrites and a database connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get my publish settings working the way I wanted I had to:

- Return web.debug.config back to it's default contents (I had some transforms in here that I was using for my staging environment)
- For every publish profile in /App_Data/PublishProfiles/, right click and select Add Config Transform to create a new config file at the root of the site (note that it will not be nested under the default web.config unless the profile is titled debug or release, kinda odd if you ask me)
- Add any relevant transforms to each of these new configs

Since all publish profiles in a website project seem to be stuck on a debug configuration, there was no way for me to avoid web.debug.config transforming my default web.config. With this solution, we simply don't use web.config for publish specific transforms.

I'd like to credit Chris O'Neill for his helpful, if verbose, answer that clued me into this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the credit and the feedback. I'm still working on my answer style, I'll try to edit it down to something more compact.

Comment: My Web.Debug.config nested underneath Web.config but Web.Release.config did not. :-(

Comment: I lost some time trying to figure this out, thanks one again to SO to the rescue.  For what it's worth, I posted a separate message on this topic trying to make sense of it all.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703040/visual-studio-2015-why-are-some-config-transforms-tied-to-publish-profiles

Answer (score 5):

> How do I add new Configurations to the dropdown?

You can't. At least not for the purpose you need to use these new configurations for.

I'll make the assumption that you really need to know this:

> How can I publish a web site without the `debug` flag being applied to the `web.config` by the debug transform?

This is already happening, just in a confusing way.

---

When you publish the site using the Publish Web Site wizard it applies the appropriate transforms to the `web.config`. In your case, `Web.Debug.Config` and `Web.Production.Config`.

And now for the confusing part:

By default, `web.debug.config` actually ***removes*** the `debug` attribute from the `web.config`.

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

This happens for legacy reasons to do with the missing Web Site project file and the underlying build tools.

---

If you want to stop the debug transformation being applied *and* you have no custom configuration in it, you can delete `web.debug.config`. Just be sure to add

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

inside the `<system.web>` element of each of your environment specific transforms (`web.Production.Config`, etc).

---

My recommendation is:

- Leave `web.debug.config` untouched. In its default state.
- Create a publish profile for each environment.
- Add a transform for each publish profile (`web.<configuration>.config`)
- Put any environment specific configuration into the appropriate transform file.

Comment: Thing is, I'm using the Debug config for url rewrites on staging that I don't need for local. In my release.config, I need new rewrites and a new connection string. So as I have it, I need both the debug and release configs.

Are you implying that I could remove the debug.config and add in, say, a staging.config? That way I still have two configs for staging and release, without release also getting the debug transforms.

Comment: What I would probably do in this case is, use `web.config` for local development and debugging. Create new solution configurations for each environment you have, UAT, Staging, Production, etc. Add `web.<configuration>.config` transforms with the customizations to use when publishing to each environment. Take everything out of `web.debug.config`, other than its default contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify/create the configuration of the project FSUResearch manually. The steps are:

In solution explorer:
Right click on the project -> Unload project -> Right click on FSUResearch (unavailable) -> Click on Edit FSUResearch.csproj

In this file you will see many ['PropertyGroup'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4w159bs.aspx) tags. These PropertyGroups consists of different combinations of configuration and platform. So create a new PropertyGroup and give your own project configurations. Make sure to give the project configuration name that is already a solution configuration name (Understand [build configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx)).

For example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Production|AnyCPU' ">
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<Optimize>false</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Save the changes and then right click on the .csproj file again and reload the project.

Comment: Thanks for the input but remember that this is a **Website Project** and, as such, does not contain a `.csproj` file nor does it have an option to Unload Project.

I do have a `.publishproj` file, but there is a comment that insists I do not edit this file. I imagine it wants to be edited by some VS dialogue. Still, this seems similar to a `.csproj` file when it comes to `<propertygroups>`. I'm just unsure of what to edit to add a release config.

Comment: Just copy one of the propertygroups and replace the configuration with your own one. Try it and see it works or not.

Comment: No dice on this, sadly : ( I copied the debug Property Group and changed the configuration to Release but I get no extra options in configuration manager even after rebuilding the site. I may be missing a step to get it to recognize the change. Fortunately, I may be on to a workaround. Thanks for the help anyways!