# Visual Studio 2015 - Why are some config transforms tied to publish profiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So chalk this one up to trying to make sense of it all...

I have a VS2015 solution with several libraries and 2 web projects.  For full disclosure, Website A is VB.NET, Website B is C#.

In website project A, my config transforms are tucked neatly underneath the web.config:

[image]

Additionally, when I look at configuration manager, the appropriate build configurations are available as well:

[image]

And all is well and like I expected it to work.

For website project B, it's different. Nestled underneath my web.config is a debug and release "transform":

[image]

HOWEVER.. these aren't respected at all when I publish my site, and I can't use the configuration manager to create a "new" configuration setting.  Instead, I had to right click the publish profile underneath app_data -> Publish Profiles and choose to add a config transform.  Once I did that, I now have a config transform sitting "elsewhere" in the solution:

[image]

Other than losing some time troubleshooting why my config's werent transforming correctly on publish, all is working well now.  What I'd like to know is..

1. Why are 2 projects in the same solution acting so differently
2. When\why did Microsoft decide to make the change where you need to edit config's based on publish profiles?